# Enabling Authentication for Access to Hyperledger Composer Playground and Blockchain Explorer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

Is there anyway to secure the access for Local Hyperledger Composer Playground and Blockchain Explorer just like the [REST Server authentication](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html)?

Answer (score 1):

The Local Composer Playground 'sees' all the cards you have on the local file system, and a user hitting that Playground can choose which card to use.  So for testing it is easy to switch between them.

You can Export a Card from Playground and send it/pass it to another person.  If they use the CLI to import the card, and start Playground they will only see that card.  In this way you can achieve authentication for Playground users but it is different to the REST server.

**Note:** that the REST server is intended to be a key element of the infrastructure for a live production system, whereas the Playground is intended for Modelling, Testing and Development - not for serious production deployment.